# Product segregation and pricing

Tags: sharia, riba, finance

Is it halal for a producer, say a farmer, to segregate his products from the same farm into lower quality and higher quality (e.g. smaller oranges vs. larger oranges) and sell them at different prices? Some people say this is riba and haram. Is there any hadith clarifying this issue?

Comment: Maybe those people misunderstand what they are talking about. See the hadith: https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2201